# Cannot convert value of type 'Measurement<UnitLength>' to type 'Measurement<Dimension>' in coercion

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, types, measurement

I have the struct Vector:

```
struct Vector{
var X : Measurement<Dimension>
var Y : Measurement<Dimension>
var Z : Measurement<Dimension>
...
```

And I  create new object, for example:

```
let test = Measurement(value: 1.5, unit: UnitLength.inches) as Measurement<Dimension>
var lVector = Vector(x: Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.meters), y: test, z: Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.meters))
```

Everything works fine. But if try to use variable from other class, I got the error: "Cannot convert value of type 'Measurement' to type 'Measurement' in coercion"

```
final class SettingsManager{
  ...
 var test  = Measurement(value: 1.5, unit: UnitLength.inches)
  ...  }
class Calculator {
 ...
 let test = SettingsManager.shared.test as Measurement<Dimension>
 var lVector = Vector(x: Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.meters), y: test, z: Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.meters))
```

I tried "as!" and got

```
Cast from 'Measurement<UnitLength>' 
to unrelated type 'Measurement<Dimension>' 
always fails
```

The same variable declared in this class works fine as I showed above. What I did wrong?

Comment: Believe the compiler. Generics are not covariant. There are no generic supertypes and subtypes. The two types really are unrelated.

Comment: @matt that's all very fine and true, but it doesn't explain why `let test = Measurement(value: 1.5, unit: UnitLength.inches) as Measurement<Dimension>` works. I think I'd regard it as a bug in the language.

Comment: @JeremyP It's a comment, not an answer. Sweeper's answer is an answer.

Comment: Anyway it does explain it just fine. `Measurement<UnitLength>` is not a `Measurement<Dimension>` but UnitLength is certainly a Dimension. Do you see?

Comment: @matt I understand exactly why it doesn't work when it doesn't work, but the same reasoning *should* apply when you construct an object and immediately try to cast it in the same expression. There's an extra hidden rule to do with type inference that is a little surprising when you first come across it.

Comment: Not really. It's the normal rule having to do with type substitution.

Comment: @JeremyP I've expanded on that part of Sweeper's answer to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

A `Measurement<UnitLength>` is not a kind of `Measurement<Dimension>`. These are unrelated types. It only works here:

```
let test = Measurement(value: 1.5, unit: UnitLength.inches) as Measurement<Dimension>
var lVector = Vector(x: Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.meters), y: test, z: Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.meters))
```

because the `Measurement(...)` calls here are actually creating `Measurement<Dimension>`s, since that is what is being expected at the callsite. `as Measurement<Dimension>` tells it that you want a `Measurement<Dimension>`, and the parameter type of `x` and `z` are also `Measurement<Dimension>`. The type inference algorithm is smart enough to see that you must also mean `Measurement<Dimension>(...)`.

`Measurement<Dimension>.init` takes a `Dimension` as its second parameter, and `UnitLength` is a subtype of that, so no problems there.

---

On the other hand, in `SettingsManager`, you declared `test` like this:

```
var test = Measurement(value: 1.5, unit: UnitLength.inches)
```

Nowhere here did you mention `Measurement<Dimension>`, so the type inference algorithm just uses the second parameter to infer that you must mean `Measurement<UnitLength>`, and so the type of `test` is `Measurement<UnitLength>`.

If you just add `as Measurement<Dimension>`

```
var test = Measurement(value: 1.5, unit: UnitLength.inches) as Measurement<Dimension>
```

it should work.

However, wouldn't it make more sense to for all three components of the vector to have the *same* type of unit?

```
struct Vector<T: Dimension>{
    var X : Measurement<T>
    var Y : Measurement<T>
    var Z : Measurement<T>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just to lay to rest the question of why this is legal:

```
let test = Measurement(value: 1.5, unit: UnitLength.inches) as Measurement<Dimension>
var lVector = Vector(x: Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.meters), y: test, z: Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.meters))
```

This shouldn't even be a question; it's just the normal substitution principle. Let's take a simpler way of expressing it. What if you don't cast?

```
let test = Measurement(value: 1.5, unit: UnitLength.inches)
```

Then `test` is inferred as `Measurement<UnitLength>`. Now let's cast:

```
let test: Measurement<Dimension> = Measurement(value: 1.5, unit: UnitLength.inches)
```

That's legal. Why? It's *not* because `Measurement<UnitLength>` is a subtype of `Measurement<Dimension>`. It isn't! It's because UnitLength is a subtype of Dimension. It is as if you had said

```
let test = Measurement(value: 1.5, unit: UnitLength.inches as Dimension)
```

Do you see? You didn't actually cast `Measurement<UnitLength>` to `Measurement<Dimension>`; that is impossible. You cast UnitLength up to Dimension, which is perfectly possible. It's no different than if you had said

```
let test2: Dimension = UnitLength.inches
```

You're always allowed to substitute a subtype where a supertype is expected. The difficulty in the original question is that `Measurement<UnitLength>` is *not* a subtype of `Measurement<Dimension>` (because Swift generics are not automatically covariant over their parameterized type).

Comment: If someone needs more clarification about covariance and invariance of generics and subtypes read [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/generics-and-subtypes-in-swift-7f27638e1b99)

Answer (score 0):

When you are declaring the `test` variable inside the `SettingsManager` you are not explicitly mentioning a type. So the swift's type inference algorithm decides the type of the variable depend on the second parameter in `Measurement(...)`.

In this case `test` has the type of `Measurement<UnitLength>`. If you used passed `UnitArea.acres` as the second parameter your variable will have the type `Measurement<UnitArea>`. Not `Measurement<Dimension>`.

If you mention the type explicitly as `Measurement<Dimension>` in the first place it will solve the issue.

```
var test : Measurement<Dimension>  = Measurement(value: 1.5, unit: UnitLength.inches)
```

Now lets check why your casting fails. You can cast a type to its sub type or super type. `UnitLength` is a subtype of `Dimension`. So you can cast between them.

But `Measurement<UnitLength>` is **NOT** a subtype of `Measurement<Dimension>`. Why ?

The reason is simple. Generics are invariant. This means that even if a generic type wraps a subtype, it doesn’t make it a subtype of a generic wrapping its superclass.

For more clarification about the above paragraph read [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/generics-and-subtypes-in-swift-7f27638e1b99).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach? Please take a look at the other answers offered, as they provide good examples.